# Post comment on youtube video by curl

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am working on a project of youtube apps. But I cannot post comment on the any videos. I am using curl and php. I have put all the function correctly but is show error of kind
If I am using

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);
```

where `$data_json` is

```
    {
    "snippet": {
  "topLevelComment": {
   "snippet": {
    "videoId": "<?php echo $videoid; ?>",
    "textOriginal": "<?php echo $comment; >"
   }
  }
 }
}

 { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError",                                   
 "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } ],  
 "code":    400, "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded
 input." } }
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mention your `content-type` header so that `youtube` knows what you are sending. By default you are right now using `form-encoded` input.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```